# Exclude row from Filter in c1flexgrid

Tags: c#, componentone

I use flexgrid with a filter. I Have a row which contains the total of values from the column in the flexgrid.

When I filter it should be visible.

So my Question is can I exclude a row from Filtering or must I set it visible manually?

Answer (score 0):

So the Workaround for this Problem is:

```
cflexgrid_AfterFilter(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   foreach(C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.Row row in cflexgrid.Rows)
   { 
     if(row == expression)
     {
       row.visible = true;
     }
   } 
}
```